# Magento address save after hook & database update

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.9

I have question about magento hook  `"customer_address_save_after"` & `"address_save_after"`. I'd to make request from this hook to API, which gets User from Magento database. Unfortunnaly at this moment, in database are old data - not updated yet.

Is there any hook in Magento, which allow me make request AFTER database update? Or maybe is any method to save data in this hook to database? Something like $customer->save() ?

```
public function afterAddressSave($observer)
{
    $customerAddress = $observer->getCustomerAddress();
    $customer = $customerAddress->getCustomer();

    if ($customer->getDefaultBillingAddress() && $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountryId()) {
        Mage::helper('iwsettings')->setStoreId($customer, $customer->getDefaultBillingAddress()->getCountryId());
    }
    $this->updateTypo3UserData($customer);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are confused a bit, the `customer_address_save_after` event is fired after data is committed to the database, however that data will not "stick" in the database if you throw an exception or a `die()` within your observer, as this causes the database to "roll back the save"

`customer_address_save_after`

- `$observer->getCustomerAddress()` This is the address being submitted
- `Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($id)` Within the observer, by passing the id of the `$observer->getCustomerAddress()->getEntityId()` we can see the exact same data as above

If however, you use `customer_address_save_before`

- `$observer->getCustomerAddress()` This is the address being submitted
- `$observer->getCustomerAddress()->getEntityId()` will be blank if new, and will have the address id if edited

This does leave you with the issue of if the address is new, you don't know the entity ID yet (not until after save). However as the Observer is loaded as a singleton you can set a flag on your observer, and fetch the address id later on after save (it'll be there). As long as your observer does not throw an exception or die it'll save to the database!

So, for your query, you can use `customer_address_save_after` (there is also a `customer_save_after` if you want the customers values). just make sure nothing throws exception, i.e. wrap your code in a `try{}catch{}` and fail it silently if it pulls an exception.

Comment: how to get street value here?

Comment: As you would on any address entity @jafar, `Mage::getModel('customer/address')->load($id)->getStreet()` if working in the after event or `$observer->getCustomerAddress()->getStreet()` if in the before event.

Comment: Observer code i tried, its not working if only one line address is there

Comment: I would take a look at the `$address->debug()` output to see where it has put your street lines, Remember `getStreet()` returns an array and you can pass it an integer to get a specific line. You might also find that the form has the wrong name value (remember the square braces for each line `street[]`) so it's not mapping what you write to the post values correctly. I've missed those square braces before :)

Comment: @jafarpinjar I would suggest you post a new question (please feel free to mention me in it or pm/post a link to it) as you are diverging from the origional question and comments are not really the place for explorring different topics. 
i would need to see your code and what you are trying to do, whereas my answer is specifically about the event order and the fact that die'ing/exiting during these events causes data rollback. I will be happy to help of course, but don't want to encure the wrath of the moderators! :D

Comment: This is my question
https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/240621/address-update-get-street-problem-magento-2